# Is there a way to get the path of a bash script when used in the source command

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to set an environment variable relative to the location of a script. I can easily find and set it for the duration of the script (test.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
export MY_VARIABLE=$(dirname $0)
echo MY_VARIABLE is : $MY_VARIABLE
```

Call:

```
./test.sh
```

Output:

```
MY_VARIABLE is : .
```

If I want to use the variable in other scripts, I need to set it with the source command. This is of course not working because I'm now not calling the test.sh script, but the source command.

```
source test.sh
```

Output:

```
dirname: illegal option -- b
usage: dirname path
MY_VARIABLE is :
```

Is there a way to define an environment variable in a script that can then be used with the source command?

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in), and [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for the hint. Using $BASH_SOURCE instead of $0 works fine and I can solve my problem. I only lack 4 reputation to answer the question and accept the answer, so here is the answer in the comment. This solution works fine for relative paths, which is ok in my case:
test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo pwd/dir     : $(PWD)/$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)

Comment: @SachaGuyer, just gave you some up votes, you should have the rep to do this now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_VARIABLE=$(PWD)/$(dirname $BASH_SOURCE)
echo MY_VARIABLE is : $MY_VARIABLE
```

Call:

```
./test2.sh
```

Output:

```
MY_VARIABLE is : /some/path/.
```

Call:

```
source ./test2.sh
```

Output:

```
MY_VARIABLE is : /some/path/.
```

Thanks @webmark and @GordonDavisson.